# Invalid XML format in web service response

Tags: xml, web-services, playframework

I am using Play 1.2.4 and I need to call a third party web service. When I get response I can't parse it properly via XPath as it contains invalid XML format.

Response has `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `<` and `>`. I've tried to decode the response with no luck. I've also checked response content which seems fine "application/soap+xml" .

So how can I replace this chars. Is there an elegant way of replacing/converting this other than simple string replacement functions using regex.

Edit: To have a better idea here is how I call web service.

```
HttpResponse response = WS.url(WS_URL)
                 .setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml") 
                 .body(wsBody)
                 .post();
```

Here is what I do to parse:

```
org.w3.dom.Document xmlDoc = response.getXML();
String textOfSelectedTag = XPath.selectText("tag", xmlDoc);
```

and XPath cannot find tag as it is not in format like `<tag>` it is like `&lt;tag&gt;`

Comment: Please show how you're calling the web service. It sounds like *something* is escaping the XML...

Comment: `String replacement`!!!!!!!!!!! **a big NO** !!

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited text with code sample. Thanks for you attention.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' I definitely agree with you. that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @huzeyfe: Okay, so that looks reasonable - but then what are you doing with the response, exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited again Jon.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' Yep you are exactly right. There are some other elements and they are in right format. I can select those nodes but problem is I don't need them.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer! Though not a solution but it is the answer!

Comment: So have you looked at the complete document that's being returned? Is it meant to be XML within XML, for example?

Comment: @JonSkeet yep first line it says: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like it's quite possibly the correct XML - it's just that it's a response which contains XML *within an element*. This would happen if you wrote a web service with a method returning a string which happened to be XML, for example. If you could post a sample of the XML, that would help.

Comment: @JonSkeet here is a sample of response I just renamed tags. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Get...Response xmlns="ns_url"><Get...Result>&lt;TAG1&gt;&lt;CHILD1_OF_TAG1&gt;value&lt;/CHILD1_OF_TAG1&gt;&lt;CHILD2_OF_TAG1&gt;value&lt;/CHILD2_OF_TAG1&gt;&lt;/TAG1&gt;</Get...Result></Get...Response></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your XML has good root elements! otherwise `xmlDoc = response.getXML();` should have error out! I think there are few or many elements in XML appear like this! If I am not wrong, it is the XML builder on Web-service that is responsible for producing such file! It is not because the way you are reading it!

In such cases, we cannot do anything on our end! I have come across such scenarios where fellow members had encountered an improperly encoded XML. All I have been suggesting for such cases is to go for modifying the code that is producing such XMLs (that is incase if you have access to) or else .. all we will be left with is regex or string manipulation! Which is though not preferred but only available method.

One reason for such XML codes I have seen is, because of usage of string concatenation! So my first suggestion would be to modify source code that is generating XML.

Regex Pattern for replacing `&lt;` to `<` and `&gt;` to `>`:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, @"(\&lt;)", @"<"), @"(\&gt;)", @">");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we are at the point of BIG NO TO String Replacement :)

Comment: ya that's a last but the least option .. well. still searching for alternatives ;)

Comment: No XML DOM method would add `&lt;` or `&gt;` in XML document(except it is CDATA). If I am guessing correctly, there has been string manipulation technique which is being used to add elements using innerXML property or something .. it is a laziest method of adding nodes. And I highly recommend to get rid of such code! It is not good! not for production environment atleast :)

Comment: I can't get rid of that code as it is not under my control. Anyway somehow I need to integrate this. Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: You are Most welcome. I am glad to help. I have updated answer with Regex code! Let me know if anything else I can do for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it looks like this is just a SOAP method which returns a *string* - and the string happens to be XML.

So you should get the contents of the `<GetFooResult>` (or whatever) tag *as a string* and then parse that as an XML document. When you get it as a string, it will have decoded the `&lt;` to `<` etc, so it'll be a valid document. *Then* you'll have a document with a root element of `TAG1` which you can then query etc.

I would suggest you use a web service library to make the call though - it should be able to abstract out everything so you can just call `getFoo()` or whatever to get the result string, then parse it as you'd expect.

Comment: Jon, many thanks for your help. WS is a web service library in PlayFramework. I think you suggest another library. Anyway I am using this library for other third party web services without any problem but as far as I understand here the problem is web service is not well designed. So your first suggestion -get the tag and reparse- makes sense and I will go with that option.

Comment: @huzeyfe: But you're just getting an HTTP response. You want something that knows about SOAP. From just the snippet of code you posted, it looks like it's pretty much just being an HTTP library. I don't think the web service itself seems badly designed - it's reasonably to return XML as a string from a web service call.

Comment: I got what you mean. Let me try with a different library if it helps. I really appreciate your kindly suggestions.